# Alternatives to libxslt when moving to node 16

Tags: node.js, libxslt

I am trying to update my project to node 16 but one of the libraries I am using is giving issues. Library name is `libxslt` (https://github.com/albanm/node-libxslt). I don't see it is maintained in a while. Is there any alternative library to use? It works with node 12.
My main purpose in using this library is to convert from one form of xml to another using xslt.

```
const libxslt = require('libxslt');    
const styleSheet = libxslt.parse(XSL_RESOURCE);
const transformedXml = await styleSheet.apply(modifiedXml);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
7022 error make: *** No rule to make target `Release/obj.target/libexslt/deps/libxslt/libexslt/common.o', needed by `Release/exslt.a'. Stop.
7022 error gyp ERR! build error
7022 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
7022 error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
7022 error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
7022 error gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
7022 error gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
7022 error gyp ERR! command "/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node" "/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
7022 error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xyz/workspace/project/node_modules/libxslt
7022 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
7022 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
7022 error gyp ERR! not ok
```

Thanks

Comment: Found anything since your post?